# What is the smallest commercially available power Mosfet?

Tags: mosfet

I've asked this question before in the airsoft section of the sports page, but with little or no help in sight I turn to you instead.

Stated question in original format:

```
I'm looking to upgrade my ICS m4 but need a mosfet that is as small as possible
since the room in my handguard is limited as is, 
and I don't want to reduce the size of my battery any further.

Which circuit should I choose?
```

---

```
Ideas:

After some consulting with a fellow on our local forum, I might try building my own.    
Here's a link to the site I found some rather good instructions --> LINK
```

The weapon is a replica of the M4 carbine and has two firing modes; semi- and fully automatic fire. The firing is controlled by a so-called switch-assembly, this assembly is a contact, riding on a plastic sled, and is connected when the trigger is pulled. This assembly is what is to be used to control the I/O for the mosfet. Semi-automatic is controlled mechanically and flicks the contact back into it's original position when a shot is fired.

My system consists of a ICS turbo 3000 motor with the following specs:

```
Input Voltage: 8.4V~11.1V
Output Power: 102W (53.82W)
RPM: 23300~26000 (8.4V)
Torque: 3875 kg.cm (2082 kg.cm)
```

The battery in question is a 1500mAh, 11,1V, 25c, Li-po with a Deans contact.

My question is as follows:
What would be the appropriate choice of mosfet switch for this setup, with regards to size, heat resistance and ruggedness. Remember, this switch will be situated within the handguard of my M4.

Comment: More info required. Power MOSFET? Logic MOSFET? NMOS? PMOS?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams
Just added "power" to the title.

Comment: What do you mean by "upgrade"?

Comment: My airsoft carbine is driven by a battery that runs a motor, and to "fire" two contactors is pushed together when I pull the trigger. With upgrade, I wish to replace this "switch assembly" with a Mosfet to reduce losses and only run the control-V through the assembly. In the future I might totaly replace the assembly with something more durable.

Comment: You also need to know the current requirements of the motor. A DPAK might be an overkill. Do you plan to mount the MOSFET on a PCB?

Comment: What makes you think this will "reduce losses"? Why are you connecting an 11.1V battery to an 8.4V motor? How can you pull the trigger 7 times per second, or is your goal to make your gun fully automatic?

Comment: Huh? What's a "ICS m4"?  Surely you can see for youself there isn't nearly enough information to understand the problem.

Comment: I'd sugest the duty cycle of the motor is less than 100%, This is how you can get away with over driving a motor.

Comment: I think there are two questions here: 1) What mosfet will meet these power requirements? and 2) having identified the requirements, what is the physically smallest mosfet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a power MOSFET, you're going to want to go with a SOT-223 case, or possibly even DPAK.

[image: http://monitor.espec.ws/section27/topic204132.html]

[image: http://www.infineon.com/cms/packages/SMD_-_Surface_Mounted_Devices/P-PG-TO252/P-PG-TO252-03-001.html]

Comment: Are you sure that it can handle the load and wont just melt?
Since V-is 11,1v and it will be switching up to 7 times/second.

Comment: You'll probably need a heatsink, or mount it on an external metal wall if possible.

Comment: Since it will rest on the inside of a metal handguard for a carbine, I think the heat problem will be less of an issue then.

Comment: Going for a TO-220 will give you a hole for a screw. It's a bit larger than a DPAK though.

Comment: That screw might just do the trick, since I don't have to secure it to the metal in some other way. How would it stand up to being shrink-tubed for water protection, would it heat up to quickly then?

Comment: You don't want something between the case and the metal; I'd consider a silicone blob over the whole thing instead.

Comment: Why didn't I think of silicone!? That's a super idea!